# SQL Server query to check max records created within a minute

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find maximum number of records created with in a minute, I could do it with a java program but am wondering if this could be done with a sql query
For example in the below data max number of records created with a minute is `18` at `2016-03-14 18:22` minute

```
      ID                 CreatedAt

    3197912         2016-03-14 18:23:38.930
    3197911         2016-03-14 18:23:34.857
    3197910         2016-03-14 18:23:34.847
    3197909         2016-03-14 18:23:16.587
    3197908         2016-03-14 18:23:14.937
    3197907         2016-03-14 18:23:11.617
    3197906         2016-03-14 18:23:00.013
    3197905         2016-03-14 18:22:59.840
    3197904         2016-03-14 18:22:54.453
    3197903         2016-03-14 18:22:51.017
    3197902         2016-03-14 18:22:37.893
    3197901         2016-03-14 18:22:35.147
    3197900         2016-03-14 18:22:29.437
    3197899         2016-03-14 18:22:27.383
    3197898         2016-03-14 18:22:23.897
    3197897         2016-03-14 18:22:22.227
    3197896         2016-03-14 18:22:20.890
    3197895         2016-03-14 18:22:19.317
    3197894         2016-03-14 18:22:18.063
    3197893         2016-03-14 18:22:15.447
    3197892         2016-03-14 18:22:08.693
    3197891         2016-03-14 18:22:04.927
    3197890         2016-03-14 18:22:01.417
    3197889         2016-03-14 18:22:00.637
    3197888         2016-03-14 18:22:00.283
    3197887         2016-03-14 18:21:59.597
    3197886         2016-03-14 18:21:56.713
    3197885         2016-03-14 18:21:56.677
    3197884         2016-03-14 18:21:56.640
    3197883         2016-03-14 18:21:56.603
    3197882         2016-03-14 18:21:56.570
    3197881         2016-03-14 18:21:56.537
    3197880         2016-03-14 18:21:55.687
    3197879         2016-03-14 18:21:51.543
    3197878         2016-03-14 18:21:49.730
    3197877         2016-03-14 18:21:47.340
    3197876         2016-03-14 18:21:46.590
    3197875         2016-03-14 18:21:40.293
    3197874         2016-03-14 18:21:34.993
    3197873         2016-03-14 18:21:29.563
    3197872         2016-03-14 18:21:18.043
    3197871         2016-03-14 18:21:16.490
    3197870         2016-03-14 18:21:13.827
    3197869         2016-03-14 18:21:00.783
    3197868         2016-03-14 18:20:46.100
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: is that within a minute relative of each other, such as `22:56.7 - 22:57.7` or within the same absolute minute `22:56.0 - 22:57.0`?

Comment: it should be with in a absolute minute `22:56.0 - 22:57.0`

Comment: just a suggestion, you might consider setting up a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to make it easier for people to test answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
select cast(dt as date), datepart(hh, dt), datepart(mm, dt), datepart(ss,dt) 
     , count(*) 
from table 
group by cast(dt as date), datepart(hh, dt), datepart(mm, dt), datepart(ss,dt)
order by count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select TOP 1 myID,DateWithMinute from 
(select count(ID) as myID,convert(varchar(16),createdat,120) as DateWithMinute
from yourtable
group by convert(varchar(16),createdat,120)
order by count(ID) desc)
```